# codeigniter error Unable to load the requested language file: language/french/french_lang.php

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am new to codeigniter 3 and I am trying to use the french translation from here https://github.com/bcit-ci/codeigniter3-translations

I've got the folder french and put it inside `application/language/` and in my config file I set `$config['language']   = 'french';`

Now when I try to submit a form I get this error :

```
Unable to load the requested language file: language/french/form_validation_lang.php
```

I went then to the autoload file and set `$autoload['language'] = array('french');`

Now I get another error :

```
Unable to load the requested language file: language/french/french_lang.php
```

any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but check this :

CI `form_validation` library uses language file for display error message.You are using required valid_email those error message is written inside form_validation_lang.php.

form_validation library loads the language `file(form_validation_lang.php)` itself whether you load or not.You can open the library file and look at the run function you will see a line `$this->CI->lang->load('form_validation');`

This file located either inside your `system/language/your_language/ or application/language/your_language/.`

That error message says you missed the file inside any of the folder.If you download the original CI files it should be inside `system/language/english/` folder.If you don't see the file download CI and restore the file there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved the problem

I found that the folder "french" permissions wasn't set correctly to be accessed by the user system of my laptop, so I just changed the permissions of the folder, and by only using `$config['language']   = 'french'` the errors are shown in french now.

Hope this will help someone!